# How to store tree with ordered children in Neo4j? How to traverse such structure in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the best way to store tree with ordered children in Neo4j?

Input:

```
1. Title 1
   Some text  1.
2. Title 2
2.1. Title 2.1
     Some text under title 2.1.
2.2. Title 2.2
     Some text under title 2.2.
```

Titles can be arbitrary and not necessarily contain numbering. Depth is arbitrary. Nodes and branches can belong to more than one tree.

How to get back all elements still ordered in one query?

Desired output:

```
|-----------+----------------------------+---------|
| Title     | Content                    | Depth   |
|-----------+----------------------------+---------|
| Title 1   | Some text under title 1.   |      0  |
| Title 2   |                            |      0  |    
| Title 2.1 | Some text under title 2.1. |      1  |
| Title 2.2 | Some text under title 2.2. |      1  |
|-----------+----------------------------+---------|
```

My question based on the fact that relational databases can retrieve such structure in one query using nested set.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. From all the options I considered, the best one looked as an integer attribute to hold index of a "line". On retrieval, records go into sorted map with this index as a key. An obvious disadvantage of this approach is a case, when something should be inserted in between objects. Full re-indexing is needed to keep integrity. For rare edits, index could be scaled by factor of 10, 100, etc., to reduce probability of immediate re-indexing.

P.S. Sorry, I don't work with Cypher, so no script here.